# How to Catch the Power Dialog Display Event in android

Tags: java, android, security, event-handling, dialog

I am working on security app and I wanna catch the event displaying power dialog.
This app is background app using accessibility.
It can work on android 12+.

How to catch power dialog event in accessibility.
I have done so many google search, but no result.
Is anybody to know about this. Please help me.